# Does provide-injection is more efficient rather than using props for deep children case (deep level) in vue 2 or 3?

Tags: javascript, web, vuejs2, vue-props

Recently, we want to do some refactor code of some vue projects, one of the aspect that we concern is can we simplify the passing props down process into deep grand child.

One of the example is we retrieve data by axios from Component A than we want to render it into component E where we must pass it as props from A -> B -> C -> D -> E where in each components except A the data will be passed as a props. When we investigate using vue devtools, we can see in each component, there's always that props with its value and if we calculate there'll be 4 variable data in overall. In our opinion, the memory that used by the 5 variable data is 5 times too and it leads to overused memory because we just need the data in component E but the process to retrive is occured in component A (inefficient)

Then we comes to several alternative i.e. using Vuex and using provide-injection that available in Vue (2/3). We prefer to using provide-injection that is lighter than Vuex. In our plan, we'll provide the data that will be passed down and just inject it into Component E. We think we can save the memory from 5 times become 2 times.

Is it correct to use provide-injection in Vue when we face deep child data pass and will it reduce memory consumption?